# Kivy - scrolling items list with custom row layout

Tags: python, kivy

I need to create in kivy list of items with custom row layout. 
Every row should have: label (with text wrapping), and two small image (side by side), below image scaled to full width (height proportionally).
How can I do that? I've already tried (CODE!):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image


import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scatter import ScatterPlane
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from os.path import join




class SMApp(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=10,
                size_hint=(None, None), width=500)



        for i in range(80):
           la = GridLayout(cols=3, padding=10, spacing=10,
                size_hint=(None, None), width=500)
           btn = Label(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, pos=(50,-200*i))
           filename = join(kivy.kivy_data_dir, 'logo', 'kivy-icon-256.png')
           l1 = Image(source=filename, size_hint_y=None)#,# pos=(0,-200*i), size=(50,50))
           l3 = Image(source=filename, size_hint_y=None)#, pos=(100,-200*i), size=(50,50))

           l2 = Image(source="las.jpg", size_hint_y=None, pos=(0,-200*i-100),  size=(1200,100))

           la.add_widget(btn)
           la.add_widget(l1)
           la.add_widget(l3)
           layout.add_widget(la)
           la2 = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=10,
                 size_hint=(None, None), width=500)

           la2.add_widget(l2)
           layout.add_widget(la2)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(500, 320),
                pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}, do_scroll_x=False)


        root.add_widget(layout)

        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SMApp().run()
```

But can't scale image "las.jpg" to full width.

I try do this in other way (CODE2):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<Boxes>:
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: 10
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    Button:
                        text: "1"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    Button:
                        text: "2"
                    Button:
                        text: "3"
                    Button:
                        text: "4"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    Button:
                        text: "5"
                    Button:
                        text: "6"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    Button:
                        text: "7"
                    Button:
                        text: "8"
                    Button:
                        text: "9"
                    Button:
                        text: "10"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    Button:
                        text: "7"
                    Button:
                        text: "8"
                    Button:
                        text: "9"
                    Button:
                        text: "10"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    Button:
                        text: "7"
                    Button:
                        text: "8"
                    Button:
                        text: "9"
                    Button:
                        text: "10"

""")


class Boxes(FloatLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Boxes()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

In this case number of columns in  rows can be different, but scrolling
do not works (all widgets fit to screen, but i need scrolling )

//edit
I tried code (method as in CODE2):

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from os.path import join
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


Builder.load_string("""
<Boxes>:
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            id: gridlayout
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                id: verticalbox

""")





class Boxes(FloatLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        widgets = Boxes()
        verticalbox = widgets.ids["verticalbox"]
        repeat = 10
        widgets.ids["gridlayout"].size_hint_y = repeat

        for a in range(0, repeat):

            layout1 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
            filename = join(kivy.kivy_data_dir, 'logo', 'kivy-icon-256.png')

            l1 = Image(source=filename, size_hint_y=None)#,# pos=(0,-200*i), size=(50,50))
            l3 = Image(source=filename, size_hint_y=None)#, pos=(100,-200*i), size=(50,50))

            btn1 = Label(text="aaaa", size_hint_y=None)
            btn2 = Label(text="aaaa", size_hint_y=None)
            btn3 = Label(text="aaaa", size_hint_y=None)

            layout1.add_widget(btn1)
            layout1.add_widget(btn2)
            layout1.add_widget(btn3)

            layout2 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')

            btn4 = Label(text="avvvvvvvvvvvaaaaaaaaaaaaaggggggggggggggggggggggggggzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", size_hint_y=None)
            layout2.add_widget(btn4)

            layout3 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')


            l2 = Image(source="jezioro.jpg")


            layout3.add_widget(l2)



            verticalbox.add_widget(layout1)
            verticalbox.add_widget(layout2)
            verticalbox.add_widget(layout3)



        return widgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Scrolling works, but image l2 does not scale to screen width, It scale to 
btn2 width. But, in other row, btn4 is scaling correct! Why?

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "all widgets fit to the screen" do you mean that their height has been squashed? If so, what happens if you set the height of your widgets so that the GridLayout's minimum height is greater than the screen height?

Comment: Thanks, now scrolling works, but it is still problem with image scaling :-(